# How can I create (approximately) the double sigmoid in the shown figure?

Tags: curve-fitting

I want to create  (approximately) the double sigmoid in the shown figure as
a function in terms of the parameters X,Y,Z, a,b,c and d.
Any idea?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This question should be migrated to the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: solution:

a=5;
b=30;
c=60;
d=100;

x=[a:0.1:d];

X=8;
Y=15;
Z=70;


n1=15;
n2=15;


y = X + Y ./(1 + exp(-n1*(x-b)))+ Z./(1 + exp(-n2*(x-c)));

plot(x,y)t

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to have gone ignored, so try something like this:

```
k = 1   # adjust this for "sharpness"

s(x) = (tanh(k * x) + 1) / 2

f(x) = X + (Y-X) * s(x-b) + (Z-Y) * s(x-c)
```

Here's an [example plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29+%3D+2+%2B+%285-2%29+*+%28%28tanh%282+*+%28x-3%29%29+%2B+1%29+%2F+2%29+%2B+%287-5%29+*+%28%28tanh%282+*+%28x-9%29%29+%2B+1%29+%2F+2%29).